# Consume a web service via WSDL url

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I need to consume a web service using a wsdl url, after searching on internet, I generated a class library using **wsdl.exe command-line**, then made instance from the class and send parameter with object from the class but I am getting this error !!

[image]

Also I generated `dll library` from wsdl url and used it in a console project but I get the same error.

```
namespace ConsoleProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Services.Service obj = new Services.Service();
            Console.WriteLine(obj.MethodName("Param1", "Param2"));
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

the source web service is **(Service.svc)** and contains many methods.

What I am missing? And how to use the files I generated using **svcutil tool**(Service.cs , output.config) I need any solution to access the service.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `[service_name]Client` class generated by **svcutil.exe** in **[service_name]Service.svc**. Also, in `output.config` should be configuration for web service. You can copy that configuration to your **App.config** and than use constructor of **client** class with parameter `string endPointConfigurationName` (it is also should be generated) to use this configuration.

**EDIT:**
You have to know the configuration name from your **App.config**. For now, let's assume that it is **"ConfigurationName"**. Then:

```
var configurationName = "ConfigurationName";
using (var client = new ServiceClient(configurationName))
{
    client.MethodName("Param1", "Param2");
}
```

use `using` keyword for automatically **Dispose** the `client` object.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to print the result of method of added service do:

```
var configurationName = "ConfigurationName";
using (var client = new ServiceClient(configurationName))
{
    Console.WriteLine(client.MethodName("Param1", "Param2"));
}
```

Comment: I coped what are in **output.config** to my **App.config**, what i should do with the **Service.cs** file that generated by  svcutil.exe, this is my first time i am dealing with wsdl web service file.. can you please give a full way. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a list of classes, that are generated in **Service.cs**? If there a class that ends with **Client** postfix?

Comment: **Service.cs** file contains 3 classes and 2 interfaces. One of the classes is (**ServiceClient**)

Comment: I've edited answer so, that you can now use it, but first, take name of the configuration from your **App.config**

Comment: thanks dear, when I copy Service.cs file  to my solution it gives errors :(

Comment: What kind of errors? Please, provide full information.

Comment: [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QW8I_zkXvt8ELxtTvbn0w2FZXE-hpNI3/view?usp=sharing ]

Comment: I see. How did you copied the **Service.cs** source? If you have copied just some part of it - it is compeltely wrong. First, copy it to your projects's folder. In Visual Studio click your mouse right button, select **Add...** -> **Existing item** and in opened dialogue choose the **Service.cs** in your project's folder.

Comment: No what I did that I pasted the file in my solution by right click > paste, your way give me the same errors ..

Comment: Then try to add to the beginning of the **Service.cs** line `using System.Runtime.Serialization;`

Comment: @Insat  did you do exactly like I sad - add this file to project via right click?

Comment: yes I added by right click, Add... -> Existing item

Comment: After I added the service reference the errors disappeared

Comment: And also try to add a reference. Open your project, right click on **"References"** -> **Add reference**. In the open dialogue find **System.Runtime.Serialization** and click add.

Comment: @Insat great! Sorry for long answer

Comment: If it works now, please, mark this answer as correct one.

Comment: I need another help, in your prev code you sent, hoe can I print the result

Comment: @Insat I've edited my answer. Just print the result of the method as is.

Comment: @Insat, if the answer is correct, please, mark this answer **as answer**.